# system('php file.php'); doesn't work, why?

Tags: php, system, execute

neither

```
<?php system('php file.php'); ?>
```

nor

```
<?php system('/usr/bin/php file.php'); ?>
```

worked. Why?

I tried with `-q`, with `!#/usr/bin/php` etc.

Comment: I think you were downvoted because "doesn't work" is an absolute "no, no" when describing a problem. Rephrase your question, and try again. :)

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but I think Till is right. Can you elaborate as to what you are trying to do and what the current output is?

Answer (score 4):

You are supposed to call it with -f, but it should work without it as well:

```
<?php system('/usr/bin/php -f file.php'); ?>
```

What do you mean by "it doesn't work"?

Did you want the contents to be outputted as if they were from your script? Use [include](http://php.net/include) or [require](http://php.net/require).

Did you want the contents in a variable? Use the [backtick operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php).

You can see what you get back from the command by using the backtick operator instead of system.

Answer (score 1):

Could be due to safe mode.

> ```
> Note: When safe mode is enabled, you can only execute files within the safe_mode_exec_dir. For practical reasons, it is currently not allowed to have .. components in the path to the executable.
> ```
>
> http://www.php.net/system.

Answer (score 0):

Without any more info... it's probably the path to the PHP executable, the path to file.php or a file permissions problem.

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you pass in a full path to 'file.php'?

Also, try to redirect the output (but stdout and stderr) to a file so that you can see the error messages that are generated.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for answering!!

For 'doesn't work' I meant: it does not return or print anything.

I have two files a.php && b.php (with all permissions) and safe_mode is off

b.php

```
<?php
$a = system('/usr/bin/php -f /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/a.php',$b);
print_r($a);
echo '-'; # for separation
print_r($b); ?>
```

and a.php

```
<?php echo 'hello world'; ?>
```

and when I run b.php from my browser (localhost/b.php) it prints:

> string(0) ""
>   -int(5)

that means $b variable is 5 but... 5 what?

Comment: Hi Barrendo, stackoverflow isn't like a forum. You should really edit your original question and add this information so it's easier to find.

Answer (score 0):

What does it say when you turn on error reporting?

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
$a = system('/usr/bin/php -f /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/a.php',$b);
print_r($a);
echo '-'; # for separation
print_r($b);
```

Comment: same thing, doesn't seem to fail

Answer (score 0):

When I change

```
system('/usr/bin/php -f /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/a.php',$b);
```

for

```
('/bin/php -f /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/a.php',$b);
```

then it says 127 instead of 5, I guess these are error codes

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$output = array();
$returnCode = 0;
exec('/usr/bin/php -f /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/a.php 2>&1', $output, $returnCode);
print_r($output);
```

The `2>&1` redirects stderr to stdout, so any error messages will be captured in `$output`

Answer (score 0):

Hang on...  What are you actually trying to achieve here?  Just run a.php and return the output to the browser?  In that case, [include](http://www.php.net/include) it.  From the looks of your posted content of a.php ( <?php echo 'hello world'; ?> ), that seems to be what you want.

If there's more to the content of a.php, then please post back and explain what you really want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$fp = popen('/usr/bin/php -f file.php', 'r');

if(false === $fp)
{
   // something bad happened: error handle
}

$contents = '';

while(false === feof($fp))
{
  $contents .= fgets($fp);
}

fclose($fp);    
echo $contents;
```

That will allow you to capture the subshell's output and trap for errors.

Answer (score 0):

}} For 'doesn't work' I meant: it does not return or print anything.

Try get a terminal/shell on your server and try your system command.  If your OS is unixy you can use something like **which php** to find the correct path to the php cli.

You did install the php cli right?  It generally isn't installed by default.

Does your web server do a chroot or something?  Perhaps the php cli doesn't exist in the environment where you are trying to use system().

Instead of trying to call a script try doing a simple **system('php -v')**.  Once you get that to correctly output the php version number then add the call to your script.

Answer (score -1):

You obviously don't understand how *system* function works. What you really need is probably [popen](http://www.php.net/popen). Start the process with *popen* and then read its output with *fgets* for example.

Alternatively, you can use the backtick operator as already suggested by others.